# Listview item color change

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, colors

Sorry for asking simmilar question again. Answer was to complex for me because i started with android 3 weeks ago and i don't know why i can't reply and past code in question.

I have a listview with 3 columns(timeschedule). First is time when bus leaves station, second is description of bus line and third is difference between the time when the bus leaves the station and the system time.

So I want to change the color of items (bus lines) which are passed. I know that listview has a method setBackgroundColor, but it works only for all items.

And this is my code:

```
        mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
       mylistglava = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

/********** Display the headings ************/
map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("Polazak", "Polazak:");
map1.put("Opis", "Napomena:");
map1.put("Kreceza", "Krece za:");
mylistglava.add(map1);

try {
    adapterglava = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylistglava,
            R.layout.vrijemebus, new String[] { "Polazak", "Opis",
                    "Kreceza" }, new int[] { R.id.Polazak, R.id.Opis,
                    R.id.Kreceza });
    list_glava.setAdapter(adapterglava);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}

/********************************************************/

/********** Display the contents ************/

for (int i = 0; i < bus.vrijeme.length; i++) {
    map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map2.put("Polazak", bus.vrijeme[i]);
    map2.put("Krece za", kreceza[i]);
    if (i < bus.opis.length)
        map2.put("Opis", bus.opis[i]);
    else
        map2.put("Opis", " ");
    mylist.add(map2);
}

try {
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.vrijemebus,
            new String[] { "Polazak", "Opis", "Krece za" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.Polazak, R.id.Opis, R.id.Kreceza });
  list.setAdapter(adapter);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

}

So can anyone implement Adapter getview() and describe me how to set this on my previous code. Maybe i will get it then.
Thanks again, 
Matija

Comment: Use custom Adapter for custom view changes.

Comment: override getView() method of custom Adapter and give conditions there for background color

Comment: you can do that but for which textview. don't understand Opis Polazak ..

Comment: it's on croatian :) Opis=description, polazak=bus departure, kreceza=diffrence between bus departure time and system time...

Comment: @user3613833 ok check my answer it should work. So if polazak is passed then change the color

Comment: @Raghunandan ok I will try it later, i'm at college now. Thank you

Comment: @user3613833 did you try? working?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes, i had some problem but now it's working fine. Example of problem: I set 
String value=tv3.getText().toString;/*tv3 is third column or third textview*/
if(value=="passed") {
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);      tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);      tv3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);}

And result was that all text in listview was colored BLACK, not only where value=="passed"; And than i put else (set other color to all 3 tv) after if and that work just fine. I don't know why i need that else but whitout it result is wrong.

Thank you for you help :)

Comment: 1. you need the else part. 2. use .equlas to compare strings both mentioned in the code posted in my post. if it helps do accept the same

Answer (score 0):

You should use [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) instead of `ListView`. In this case you'll be able to customize any item you want.

Comment: why op should `GridView`? You can do it with Listview also

Comment: Sure, it's possible to do it with `ListView`, but not effective.

Comment: why is that so? I see no problem at all

Comment: In case of `GridView` it's easier to manipulate items in a row/column. You can use 3 lightweight adapters instead of 1 heavy. The less code inside `getView()` the better, because this function is called a huge number of times.

Comment: i don't think so. the listview works fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works

Comment: In terms of application smooth work, the best solution will be a usage of a `ViewHolder` pattern both for `GridView` and `ListView`

Comment: @Raghunandan yeap, they use `ViewHolder` I mentioned above

Comment: also gridview you can specify the number of columns but not rows.

Comment: Actually you can do it. Just add a fixed number of items and don't change it. The same is for `ListView`. Consider `GridView` is a usual matrix from math.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52679/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-ivan-rylach)

Answer (score 0):

Override `getView` of Adapter

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.vrijemebus,
        new String[] { "Polazak", "Opis", "Krece za" }, new int[] {
                R.id.Polazak, R.id.Opis, R.id.Kreceza })
       {
           @Override
           public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
           {
               View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
               TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Polazak);
               // based on condition. set color to  the required textview
               String value = tv.getText().toString();
               if(value.equals("passed"))
               {
               tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
               }else
               {
               tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
               }

               return v;
           }
       };
```